# How can I make this simple code more efficient without repeating the for loops for each year?

Tags: c++

So this program produces a bar chart(very basic) showing the population growth at a 20 year intervals during the past 100 years.

It's working as intended, yet I feel there has to be a more efficient way of looping while obtaining the same result, instead of repeating the for loop for each year. I'd also like to keep the solution within the level displayed in the code (intro to C++)

The People.txt contains the following:

> 2000    4000    5000    9000    14000    18000

And this is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile; // File stream object
    int number;

    // Open the input file
    inputFile.open("People.txt");


    cout << "PRAIRIEVILLE POPULATION GROWTH\n" << "(each * represents 1000 people)\n";

    //1910's bar
    cout << "1910 ";
    inputFile >> number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //1930's bar
    cout << "1930 ";
    inputFile >> number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //1950's bar
    cout << "1950 ";
    inputFile >> number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //1970's bar
    cout << "1970 ";
    inputFile >> number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //1990's bar
    cout << "1990 ";
    inputFile >> number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    //2010's bar
    cout << "2000 ";
    inputFile >> number;
    for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Close the file
    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Hint:** use two loops only, one of which should be nested (which one? think!).... and an array of <guess>.

Comment: This belongs in code review. I personally cannot think of any real ways to simplify it. You could take the brackets off the for statements and it might look nicer. Really, though, you should be error checking opening the file, and be sure that there is the correct number of integers in the People.txt. (edit: I may have not understood the question.)

Comment: @EvanCarslake this should give you an idea on how simple the code is set to display. http://i.imgur.com/8TcpTkh.png

Comment: @Nawaz Thank you I will give it another go. I was trying hard to nest loops, but I never quite got it right. I think the problem was that inputFile >> number was not updating in the loop. I think I need to put that in a array, so that I can call each number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code should look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile; // File stream object
    int number;

    // Open the input file
    inputFile.open("People.txt");


    cout << "PRAIRIEVILLE POPULATION GROWTH\n" << "(each * represents 1000 people)\n";

    for(int y = 1910; y <= 2010; y += 20)
    {
        cout << y << ' ';
        inputFile >> number;
        for (int i = 1; i < number; i+=1000)
        {
            cout << '*';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Close the file
    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that quotation marks (string literal) have been changed to single quotes (character literal) for the asterisk. Operator << will be more efficient this way because it does not need to dereference the pointer a string literal in fact means, but it gets a mere character which fits in a register.

Comment: This is it. Very simple! Thanks. I was not seeing the loop clear while trying to nest it.

Answer (score 1):

Something off the top of my head:

```
// Without error checking, something like this:
// Assuming it starts at year 1910, at 20 year intervals

int number = 0;
int year = 1910;

while (inputFile >> number) {
    cout << year << " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i += 1000) {
       cout << "*";
    }

    cout << "\n";

    year += 2000;          
}
```